Difference between dividend swap and dividend futures
My understanding has been that a dividend swap, like any other type of swap involves pricing a fixed leg ($A$), with some dividend amount per period as the strike, and a variable leg ($B$) with the expected dividend payment as the floating value for each period. We then discount each payment and do $PV = PV_B - PV_A$.
The price of a dividend future should just be equal to the discounted expected future dividends up to maturity.
I've read now in https://www.trading-volatility.com/Dividend%20Swaps%20and%20Futures%20-%20Colin%20Bennett.pdf that there is no difference between the two and the two have practically the same price. Can someone explain to me how and why a dividend swap and a dividend future should be the same? Is the fixed rate in practice $0$ and therefore we have the same price?

If you go long dividends via a div swap, you enter at a certain strike (say 100). If divs settle at 102, you make 2 at expiry of the swap. Before that, the fair strike of the swap can change, and your div swap is marked to market to that (as you can take the inverse position and lock in the difference in strikes).
If you go long dividends via a div future, you enter the future at a certain price (again 100). Then if the div future price goes to 102, you make 2 immediately. The dividend future price is forced to converge to final dividend settlement because it settles there.
The marginal difference between the two, is that in dividend swaps, you are subject to discounting. Because you receive the cash flows only at expiry. So today you make only the Present Value of your 2 points of dividends. Whereas in dividend futures, you make the 2 points of dividends immediately, given you entered the future at 100 and can now exit at 102.

Do dividend futures actually trade?

In a country far away... https://www.eurex.com/ex-en/markets/did/exd/EURO-STOXX-50-Index-Dividend-Futures-946316

Thanks for the answer @Soumirai, just to reiterate:  theres indeed no fixed leg like in an interest rate swap, as our strike is the current market expectation of future dividends for the underlying and so the difference between div swap and div fut is only in Pnl as we discount the diff between market rate and strike for swap but not for the future.
This means they are practically the same in terms of PV, right? Something like $$PV = (\mathbb{E}[D(T)|\mathcal{F}_0] - D(0))e^{-rT}$$

Yes, the swap has a PV (your formula), while the div fut technically has 0PV because its performance is settled daily
